# This following code is file read/write in a single file. but this code is not able to create file

Tags: c++, file-handling

I am writing a program which reads and writes the records of students using classes. This program does't open a file. so I am not able to read data from file.

```
class Student
{
   private:
      unsigned roll ;
      char name[30];
      float perc;

   public:
      void getvalue()
      {
         cout<<"enter rollno , name and percentage :\n";
         cin>>roll;
         cin.ignore(); 
         cin>>name>>perc;
      }

      void  display()
      {
         cout << "\nRoll No : " << roll << "\nName : " << name
            << endl << "percentage : " << perc << endl;
      }
};

int main()
{
   char choice;
   Student st ;
   fstream file1;

   file1.open("stud_rec1.bin", ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out );
   do
   {
      cout<<"\n Detail of student  :\n";
      st.getvalue();

      file1.write((char*)(&st) , sizeof(st));

      cout<<"\nwant to input more record(y/n) : ";

      cin>>choice;

   } while(tolower(choice) == 'y');

   file1.seekg(0,ios::beg);

   while(file1.read((char*)(&st) , sizeof(st))   )
   {
      cout<<"1";
      st.display();
   }

   file1.close();

   getch();
}
```

Comment: please always check whether you file was opened successfully or not before any other file operations

Answer (score 0):

When you call `fstream::open()` with mode set to `ios::out|ios::in`, the file can be opened only if the file exists. If the file does not exist, `fstream::open()` fails. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open and the related http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open.

Change

```
file1.open("stud_rec1.bin", ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out );
```

to

```
file1.open("stud_rec1.bin", ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out);
if ( !file1.is_open() )
{
   file1.clear();
   file1.open("stud_rec1.bin", ios::out); //Create file.
   file1.close();
   file1.open("stud_rec1.bin", ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out);

   // If the file still cannot be opened, there may be permission
   // issues on disk.
   if ( !file1.is_open() )
   {
      std::cerr << "Unable to open file " << "stud_rec1.bin" << std::endl;
      exit(1);
   } 
}
```

Comment: thank u sir for your quick response. i really appreciate your gesture.